# Rails testing with Zeus and Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sidekiq, zeus

In my spec_helper I have `require "sidekiq/testing"`. If I put `Sidekiq::Testing.fake!` right after that line, I get the uninitialized constant Sidekiq::Testing error when I run `zues test spec/path/to/spec.rb`

Without adding in that require, zeus will boot up fine, but I get a undefined method drain error for one of my Sidekiq workers. If I run the specs without zeus, then all specs run just fine.

Anyone know if there's some weird order all of this stuff has to be in for it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, I updated the version of Sidekiq to the current last one 2.15.2 and it worked for me.